# AJAX post data almost saving to the db?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Testing the modules, the AJAX is posting properly in the browser's console.log, and the Node.js/express4 mongoose .save method is saving properly into MongoDB (testing with [Postman - REST Client](http://www.getpostman.com/))

For some reason, the AJAX post data has yet to make it to the db, though it accurately logs the data..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#SubmitBtn').click(function() {

        var message = $( "#message" ).val();

        console.log(message); // logs as the "user's message"

        var AjaxPostData = {'message' : message};

        console.log(AjaxPostData);  // logs as [object Object]

          // make an ajax call
          $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: AjaxPostData,
            type: 'post',
                url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories",
                success: foundAllSuccess,
                error: foundAllFailure
            });

        console.log(AjaxPostData.message);  // logs as the "user's message"
    });
});
```

Express4 routing:

```
var router = express.Router();  // an instance of the express Router
var Story = require('./app/models/story');  // load the mongoose model

router.route('/stories')

    // create a story (accessed at POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var story = new Story();  // create a new instance of the Story model
        story.message = req.body.message;  // set the message, from the request

        console.log(req.body.message); // logs with Postman, yet the ajax post

        // save the story, and check for errors
        story.save(function(err) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Story "' + story.message + '" Created' });

        });
    })

app.use( '/api/v1', router );  // all of the routes are prefixed
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the nature of the error here? When you make the AJAX post is your console.log of `req.body.message` logging with the appropriate content? Also I suggest using `new Story({message: req.body.message}).save(callback)` as it's a bit cleaner. Finally, I would remove the inverted commas in your definition of `AjaxPostData` as they're not necessary as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Michael the console log of req.body.message is not logging for the ajax post.. thanks for the suggested formatting.. will test it all

Comment: @Michael revised the formatting to your cleaner suggestion.. console is logging req.body.message with POSTMAN testing, not ajax.. removed the inverted commas too, still no ajax data saving.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `data: AjaxPostData,`

With `data : JSON.stringify(AjaxPostData),`
I dont believe the data is being passed correctly and thats why it sends at [Object object]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the ajax click event needed  `e.preventDefault();` or  `return false;`

```
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // do something
});

$('#SubmitBtn').click(function() {

    //do something

    return false;
});
```

Either work in this case..though here's a great post on the differences: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)